# Unresolved Dependencies while building Spark1.3.0 with Sbt

Tags: sbt, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

I am trying to build spark 1.3.O on standalone Ubuntu 14.04. I am using the sbt command i.e. "sbt/sbt assembly" to build it. This command works pretty good with spark version 1.1 however, it gives following error with spark 1.3.0. Any help or suggestions to resolve this would highly be appreciated.

```js
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES ::
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.3.0: configuration not p ublic in org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.3.0: 'test'. It was requir ed from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.3.0 test
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn] Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn] org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:1.3.0 ((com.typesafe. sbt.pom.MavenHelper) MavenHelper.scala#L76)
[warn] +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.10:1.3.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-network-comm on_2.10;1.3.0: configuration not public in org.apache.spark#spark-network-common _2.10;1.3.0: 'test'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle _2.10;1.3.0 test
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:278)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:175)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:157)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:128)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:56)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:64)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRet ries$1(Locks.scala:78)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala: 97)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:64)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:123)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:120)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:151)
at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:157)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala :1318)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala :1315)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1 345)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1 343)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1342)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1360)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1300)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1275)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22 6)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22 6)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric tions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51 1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor. java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor .java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (network-shuffle/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.3.0: configuration not public in or g.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.10;1.3.0: 'test'. It was required from org .apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.10;1.3.0 test
```

Comment: Make sure your maven settings look in the maven central, and execute `sbt/sbt clean update assembly`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JDK 8.0 ? If so, this may be an instance of javadoc setting some warnings ('missing' javadoc for some modules) as errors. Have a look there:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4543

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4193

The PR that fixes it is there:
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3058